# Dynamic information based on shipping method and cart total In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

This seems like it should be simple but I can't quite get there.

*Goal: I need to display a notice to users when they change their shipping method if the cart total is less than the required limit.*

I wrote a function in functions.php file

```
function min_delivery(){

    //Get Chosen Shipping Method//
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 
    //end method


    //check if they've chosen delivery
    if ($chosen_shipping == 'flat_rate:2') {

        //set cart minimum
        $minimum = 15.00;
        //get cart total - 2.00 is the delivery fee
        $total = WC()->cart->total-2.00;
        // check if the total of the cart is less than the minium
        if ( $total < $minimum ) {
            //check if it's in the cart
            if( is_cart() ) {

                   wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Minimum £15.00 for Delivery' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( $total )
                ), 'error' 
            );
            //else at checkout
            } else {

                wc_add_notice( 
                    sprintf( 'Min 15.00 for Delivery' , 
                        wc_price( $minimum ), 
                        wc_price( $total )
                    ), 'error' 
                );
            }

            }//end of total less than min

    //else they have pick up
    } else {
        //set cart minimum
        $minimum = 4.50;
        //get cart total - 2.00 is the delivery fee
        $total = WC()->cart->total-2.00;
        if ( $total < $minimum ) {
            //check if it's in the cart
            if( is_cart() ) {

                   wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Minimum £15.00 for Delivery' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( $total )
                ), 'error' 
            );
            //else at checkout
            } else {

                wc_add_notice( 
                    sprintf( 'Min 15.00 for Delivery' , 
                        wc_price( $minimum ), 
                        wc_price( $total )
                    ), 'error' 
                );
            }

            }//end of total less than min
    }//end pickup/delivery else


}//end function
```

Now calling this function with the before checkout form works great

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'min_delivery' );
```

However my issue is when people update the shipping on the fly, i.e choose between them. I figured there would be a hook I could use such as one of these

```
//add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'min_delivery' );
//add_action( 'update_order_review' , 'min_delivery' );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' , 'min_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'min_delivery' );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', 'min_delivery' );
//add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'min_delivery');
```

However none of them do the job. When i look into the console, when updating there is an AJAX Call to `?wc-ajax=update_order_review` but I couldn't seem to hook into that

I'm wandering if i'm barking up the wrong tree here and you can even amend the page through hooks and functions as PHP has already rendered?

As per the goal the whole point is to restrict order/payment for delivery where cart total is less than £15 and notify the customer of the reason.

Comment: Of course, checking now. Thanks for adding

Answer (score 1):

I have revisited and tried to simplify your code. The following will add conditionally a custom information message (refreshed dynamically) in cart and checkout totals table after shipping rows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'shipping_notice_displayed', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'shipping_notice_displayed', 20 );
function shipping_notice_displayed() {
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' ) >= 2 ||
        did_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ) >= 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Chosen Shipping Method
    $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
    $chosen_shipping_method    = explode(':', $chosen_shipping_method_id)[0];
    $cart_subtotal             = WC()->cart->subtotal; // No need to remove the fee

    // Settings
    $cart_minimum1             = 4.5;
    $cart_minimum2             = 15;

    // HERE define the cart mininimum (When delivery is chosen)
    if ( $cart_subtotal < $cart_minimum2 && $chosen_shipping_method != 'flat_rate' ) {
        $cart_minimum = $cart_minimum1;
    } elseif ( $cart_subtotal < $cart_minimum2 && $chosen_shipping_method == 'flat_rate' ) {
        $cart_minimum = $cart_minimum2;
    }

    // Display a message
    if( isset($cart_minimum) ){
        // The message
        $message =  sprintf( '%s %s for Delivery' ,
            is_cart() ? 'Minimum' : 'Min',
            strip_tags( wc_price( $cart_minimum, array('decimals' => 2 ) ) )
        );

        // Display
        echo '</tr><tr class="shipping info"><th>&nbsp;</th><td data-title="Delivery info">'.$message.'</td>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]